# Ignoring text to compute regions in image?

Tags: image-processing

Given this image (from Sculley et al "Hidden Technical Debt in Machine Learning Systems"), how can the relative areas of the boxes be computed?

In particular, the text interferes with most morphological and other operators:

[image]

ImageLines didn't work even with `"Segments"->True` options.

`ImageCorners` identifies most - though not all - corners of rectangles (desired) but also tags most areas of text even with large minimum spacing parameter, eg 20.

```
corners = debt[0] // Binarize // ImageCorners[#, 2, 0, 20] &
```

[image]

The strategy, given only the box corners, would be to computationally fit them to rectangles and then solve for the areas.

Is there a more direct, feasible approach that does not require manual removal of text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ComponentMeasurements` has a handy measurement `EnclosingComponentCount` that's 0 for the (outermost) boxes, and >= 1 for text inside the boxes:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vrE2.png"];    
comp = ComponentMeasurements[
  ColorNegate[Binarize[img]], {"BoundingBox", 
   "EnclosingComponentCount"}, #EnclosingComponentCount == 0 &]
```

Which finds all boxes:

```
HighlightImage[img,
 comp /. (n_ -> {bbox_, ___}) :> Rectangle @@ bbox]
```

[image]

## Response to comment:

> what's the correct way of doing ImageTake based on the individual output box coordinates?

The easiest way is to use `ImageTrim`:

```
comp /. (n_ -> {bbox_, ___}) :> ImageTrim[img, bbox]
```

[image]

and you can use `TextRecognize` to read the text inside the box:

```
comp /. (n_ -> {bbox_, ___}) :> 
  Labeled[ImageTrim[img, bbox], TextRecognize[ImageTrim[img, bbox]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Incidentally, here are the area ratios: `(comp /. (n_ -> {bbox_, ___}) :> Rectangle @@ bbox ) // Map[Area] // 
  Sort // Query[{Identity, First} /* Apply[Divide]]` . results `(* {1., 6.375, 10.237, 10.6074, 10.8121, 11.1833, 13.2904, 13.7338, \
17.1404, 27.0344} *)`

Comment: Would be killer if the rectangles could be associated to each text as label.

Comment: what's the correct way of doing `ImageTake` based on the individual output box coordinates? I tried for example `ImageTake[img, 
 Sequence @@ ({{1232.`, 6.`}, {1506.`, 568.`}} // Transpose)]` but got an out of range error.

Comment: @alancalvitti: `ImageTake` doesn't use coordinates, it uses indices. Here's a good explanation: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html#1708646374

Comment: Using the coordinate xform in the tutorial, `indexToImage[height_][{x_, y_}] := { height - y + 1/2, x + 1/2};` this image is 584px high, but when I try an example rectangle: `r1 = rectangles[1] // 
  Map[indexToImage[debt[0] // ImageDimensions // Last]]`, (where `r1` is `1 -> {{1232., 6.}, {1506., 568.}}`) and then `ImageTake[img, Sequence @@ Transpose[Reverse[r1]]]` the rectangle is returned but in reverse (ie the text is reversed). What's the appropriate way to package arguments here?